# Swift prorgamming IOS

Tags: swift

How to create an attributed text that can link to a particular URL and underline only the clickable string. 
How to use the UIAttributed text such that a tap on it links the current view controller to a particular URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
        return false
    }
}
```

You can find all the detailed information from here.

> It’s fairly easy to make hyperlinks clickable in a UITextView. To do
>   so, go to the Attributes Inspector of the view and check off the
>   “Links” option in the “Detection” field.

[How to make tappable link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-tappable-links-in-nsattributedstring)